# I want fast entry into chart but plotting slowly

Tags: java, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I Using MPAndroidChart for random float Entry to plotting.
the problem is i want to put in Random Entry data per 3ms(300 Data/sec) then plotting data by 1 second or longer.
I Tried apply animation effect on chart, load chart from Thread with delay, Increase X-Range, load Chartdata from Thread with delay but these are all failed. Here this is code what i have now. please help.
P.S. this is for FFT(Fast Fourier Transform) with Analog Sensor Data

```
private void feedMultiple() {

    if (thread != null) {
        thread.interrupt();
    }

    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    float a = (float) Math.random() * 400;
                    addEntry(a);
                    thread.sleep(60);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

public void addEntry(float a) {

```
    LineData data = mChart.getData();

    if (data != null) {
        ILineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
        // set.addEntry(...); // can be called as well
        if (set == null) {
            set = createSet();
            data.addDataSet(set);

        }
        predict(a);

        data.addEntry(new Entry(set.getEntryCount(), a), 0);
        data.notifyDataChanged();

        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(50);

        mChart.moveViewToX(data.getEntryCount());
    }
}
```